# Promise callback queue with priority for some callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, priority-queue

My code needs to perform a multitude of async actions simultaneously and handle their promises in a specific sequential way.

What I mean by "specific sequential way" ==> Assume you are starting promises `promise1`, `promise2`, `promise3` in that order, and that promise3 actually resolves first, and promise2 second, then what I want is to process `promise3`, `promise2` and `promise1` sequentially in that order

Let's consider a `timeout` async function that times out after X seconds, and `fetchMyItem1`, `fetchMyItem2`, that return promises which, when fulfilled, should execute a different code depending whether `timeout` has resolved or not.

For a concrete scenario, imagine there is a customer waiting at the counter for an item to be delivered, and either the customer stays and we can serve him directly at the counter by bringing one item at a time, or the customer goes away (`timeout`) and we have to ask a waiter to come so that when the items arrive, he/she can bring the items to him. Note here that even when one item is being delivered, the other items should still be undergoing delivery (the promises are pending), and might even arrive (be fulfilled) while the customer is being served one item or the server arrives.

Here is some code to start with

```
const allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises = [fetchMyItem1(), fetchMyItem2(), ...]
const customerLeavesCounterPromise = timeout()

const waiter = undefined

const allPromisesToBeFulfilled = [...allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises, customerLeavesCounterPromise]

// LOOP
const itemDeliveredOrVisitorLeft = await Promise.all(allPromisesToBeFulfilled)

if hasCustomerLeft(itemDeliveredOrCustomerLeft) {
  // hasCustomerLeft allows us to detect if the promise that resolved first is `customerLeavesCounterPromise` or not
  waiter = await callWaiter()
} else {
  // An item has arrived
  if (waiter) {
    deliverItemViaWaiter(itemDeliveredOrVisitorLeft)
  } else {
    deliverItemAtCounter(itemDeliveredOrVisitorLeft)
  }
}
// remove itemDeliveredOrCustomerLeft from allPromisesToBeFulfilled

// END loop
```

I am not sure how to implement a loop for this scenario. Promises must be accumulated into a queue as they resolve, but there is a priority for a specific promise in the queue (the timeout promise should be executed asap when it arrives, but after finishing the processing of the current promise if a promise fulfilment is already being processed)

Comment: Promises do represent the *result of an asynchronous action*, not the *asynchronous action* itself.

Comment: I do not fully understand what the process exactly is (I roughly do as it seems to be online shopping with a limited amount of goods in stock). I think that you might have some misunderstandings about Promises, so it might be better if you try to explain the process and the edge cases without the terms of promises.

Comment: I have edited my question, is it better ? Given that a promise can be pending or fulfilled (resolved/rejected) I had indeed assimilated a promise to the asynchronous action itself, thanks for the clarification on this.

Comment: Is the customer/counter example is a true reflection of your desire to "process promise3, promise2 and promise1 sequentially in that order"? Say the shop in question was a restaurant, then the customer would expect all items to be delivered to the counter all at once, or to a table in starter-main-dessert sequence  regardless of which order they are prepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code needs to perform a multitude of async actions simultaneously and handle their promises in a specific sequential way.

You could use streams to consume the promises, as streams are essentially queues that process one message at a time.

The idea (i.e. not tested):

```
import { Readable, Writable } from 'stream';
let customerHasLeft = false;
/*const customerLeavesCounterPromise = */timeout() // your code...
.then(() => { customerHasLeft = true; }); // ... made boolean
// let's push all our promises in a readable stream
// (they are supposedly sorted in the array)
const input = new Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read: function () { // don't use arrow function: we need `this`
    const allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises = [fetchMyItem1(), fetchMyItem2(), ...]; // your code
    // put everything, in the same order, in the output queue
    allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises.forEach(p => this.push(p));
    this.push(null); // terminate the stream after all these
  }
});
// let's declare the logic to process each promise
// (depending on `timeout()` being done)
const consumer = new Writable({
  write: async function (promise, uselessEncoding, callback) {
    try {
      const order = await promise; // wait for the current promise to be completed
    } catch (e) {
      /* delivery error, do something cool like a $5 coupon */
      return callback(e); // or return callback() without e if you don't want to crash the pipe
    }
    if (customerHasLeft) { /* find a waiter (you can still `await`) and deliver `order` */ }
    else { /* deliver `order` at the counter */ }
    callback(); // tell the underlying queue we can process the next promise now
  }
});
// launch the whole pipe
input.pipe(consumer);
// you can add listeners on all events you'd like:
// 'error', 'close', 'data', whatever...
```

#### EDIT: actually we want to process promises as they resolve, but sequentially (i.e. a single post-process for all promises)

```js
let customerHasLeft = false;
timeout() // your code...
.then(() => { customerHasLeft = true; }); // ... made boolean
const allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises = [fetchMyItem1(), fetchMyItem2(), ...];
const postProcessChain = Promise.resolve(); // start with a promise ready to be thened
// add a next step to each promise so that as soon as one resolves, it registers
//  as a next step to the post-process chain
allItemsToBeDeliveredPromises.forEach(p => p.then(order => postProcessChain.then(async () => {
  // do something potentially async with the resulting order, like this:
  if (customerHasLeft) { /* find a waiter (you can still `await`) and deliver `order` */ }
  else { /* deliver `order` at the counter */ }
})));
```

Comment: I like the idea of stream processing, but I'm not sure your code does what I need. are async actions really performed simultaneously with your current code ? I believe what I actually need to do is to simply start all the async actions with something like `fetchMyItem1.then ( (data) => inputStream.push(data) )` in order to feed my input Stream with the resolution of my promises. The remaining question is how do I close my processing stream after all promises have resolved (but I can most likely handle this in the write function).

Comment: `Promise.all` only aggregates several promises into a single one that will resolve when all promises have resolved.
What my code intends to do: start all `fetchMyItemX()` processes, and pass the promises these functions return _in the order they were declared_ to the pipe. Then the second stream waits for each promise it receives to resolve before processing it and then fetching the next promise in queue.

Comment: If you do `fetch().then(this.push)`, you won't know in which order they're pushed to the queue (because `fetch1` may resolve _after_ `fetch2`).
In my code, the readable stream notifies its ending with `this.push(null)`, AFAIK it's _the_ way to implement a readable end.

Comment: Hey that was actually the point, I don't need to know in which order they are pushed in the queue, on the opposite : I want to process the first promise that resolves first.

EDIT : ah I understand, my "specific sequential way" description was a bit confusing, I'll edit

Comment: That's the concept of a queue: first in, first out! ;) If you push 1,2,3, you process 1 then 2 then 3. (Contrary to promises, which resolve... when they resolve.)

Comment: Yes, I understand the confusion : I was thinking of "queuing" based on which promise resolved first, not which async action I started first. So if promises 1,2,3 are started in order 1,2,3 but actually resolve in the order 3,2,1, I do want to process in the order 3,2,1 (only after the callback of promise 3 is finished do I want to start the callback for promise 2, etc).

Comment: Ow OK, it's indeed not "in a specific sequential way", it's more like "in the fastest sequential way". This code doesn't answer your question then.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris just added an edit that should do what you need. Or at least provide the idea - an idea. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> one of them must have the effect that, whenever it fulfils, it should alter the processing of other fulfilled promises that have not yet been processed or are not yet being processed.

Do you run them all together? Something like:

```
promise1 = asyncFunc1()
promise2 = asyncFunc2()
promise3 = asyncFunc3()

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(//sometthing)
```

If yes, it can't be done, unless the promise2 function and promise3 function aren't waiting for an event, a lock, or something handled by the promise1 function.

If this is the case is better to organize the promises like:

```
asyncFunc1()
    .then(() => asyncFunc2(paramIfOk))
    .catch(() => asyncFunc2(paramIfFail))
```

In your example:

```
const allItemsToBeDelivered = [myPromise1(), myPromise2(), ...]
```

myPromise1() code should wait for the item to be delivered **and** check if someone is waiting for it. It's a model/code design problem, not a promise one.

Another way to do it is consider some event driven logic: an entity Customer has a listener for the delivered event that will be fired by the waitItemDelivered() promise just before resolve itself.

EDIT: as requested here a little more elaboration on the event-driven solution.

Short answer: it highly depend on your software design.

It's already something released and running in production? Be carefull with changes like this. If it's a service that you are developing you're still in time to take in consideration some logic changes. A solution that doesn't change radically how is working but use an events is not that great, mixing patterns never pay off on long term.

Example:

```
const events = require('events');

class Customer() {

    constructor(shop) {
        this.emitter = new events.EventEmitter()

        this.shopEventListener = shop.emitter
        this.setupEventLinstening() // for keeping things clean in the constructor

        // other properties here
    }

    setupEventLinstening() {
        this.shopEventListener.on('product-delivered', (eventData) => {
            // some logic
        })
    }

    buyProduct() {
        // some logic

        this.emitter.emit('waiting-delivery', eventData)
    }
}

class Shop() {

    constructor(shop) {
        this.emitter = new events.EventEmitter()

        // other properties here
    }

    addCustomer(customer) {
        customer.emitter.on('waiting-delivery', (eventData) => {
            // some logic

            self.waitDelivery().then(() => self.emitter.emit('product-delivered'))
        })
    }

    waitDelivery() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // some logic

            resolve()
        })
    }
}

// setup
const shop = new Shop()
const customer = new Customer(shop)
shop.addCustomer(customer)
```

This is a new way of seeing the logic, but a similar approach can be used inside a promise:

```
const waitDelivery = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    logisticWaitDelivery().then(() => {
        someEmitter.emit('item-delivered')
        resolve()
    })
}

const customerPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    someListener.on('item-delivered', () => {
        resolve()
    })
}

promiseAll([waitDelivery, customerPromise])
```

Comment: Yes all of them run together. So some sort of lock is needed. I believe the event driven logic is the way to go about it if, could you elaborate ?

Comment: Edited the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 queues, the second starting after the first ends:

```
var highPriority=[ph1,ph2,...]//promises that have to be executed first
var lowPriority=[pl1,pl2,...]//promises that have to wait the high priority promises
Promise.all(highPriority).then(()=>{
    Promise.all(lowPriority)
})
```

Comment: The problem is that all asynchronous actions must be executed at the same time

Comment: JS is a single thread language, they will never be executed at the same time, they will be executed serially as soon as the CPU is available, you can use promises to tell what is executed first, later, or let them free, but never parallely

Comment: When I mean at the same time, I mean that those functions are asynchronous and each waiting for I/O, so even if JS is single threaded we don't know in advance which will be fulfilled first and any could be fulfilled first. What `Promise.all()` does in a nutshell :-)

Comment: are these async actions granted to finish or they can no finish at all? does they finish one time or more than one time? promises are for actions that finish usaully at most a single time, and relying on waiting them needs that they finish at least one time

Comment: if they are counted and is granted that they ends always and no more dat once, you can use Prmise.all() on them and then do your action, otherwise you have to identify a situation when not all are executed or executed more than once, and you can check this situation

Comment: Some of those actions are API calls to our servers, and it may happen that one server could hang due to too much traffic for example (but in this case I believe the `node-fetch` implementation would most likely time out the request at some point).
Otherwise, there's no reason those actions would not finish. Regarding how "many" times they finish, I'm not sure if this answers your questions, but regarding the said API calls, I'm currently chaining a fetch API call and then calling .json() when the promise resolves, which gives me another promise...